# Facebook Pixel tracking pushState page view, but with wrong url

Tags: facebook, facebook-pixel

I'm trying to use `history.pushState` to simulate a page view, which Facebook Pixel supports:

https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2017/05/29/tagging-a-single-page-application-facebook-pixel/

Let's say I make a request to `https://example.com/original-url`. The Pixel Helper browser extension and my browser tools report a request made to something like this `https://www.facebook.com/tr/?id=123&ev=PageView&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Foriginal-url&rl=referring-url&if=false&ts=123&v=2.7.17...`  (note the `dl` param appears to be reporting the url of the page I'm on).

Then from this page the call `history.pushState({}, 'Foo', "/foo")` is made. My browser's url is updated to `https://example.com/foo`, and I can see an additional pixel request being made, but that request's query string has the original page url in it, not "`/foo`", as I would expect. Eg. it still looks like the following. Only the id has changed.

`https://www.facebook.com/tr/?id=456&ev=PageView&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Foriginal-url&rl=referring-url&if=false&ts=123&v=2.7.17...`

To me, this seems incorrect, like it's recording a second page view to `/original-url` when it should instead be recording a view to `/foo`.

Any experts with experience in this area have any comments or explanation?

Comment: We are also experiencing this. The request you are seeing matches the `noscript`'s img src (and Chrome reports the type as `gif`). In our case, I suspect the noscript is getting re-injected on every view change due to known/documented adverse behaviour in React-Router#component (which re-renders the container on every view change).

Comment: It's not the `noscript` (I tried removing it, and those requests are still made).